# 301 Redirect in .htaccess for re-submitting URL-s

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to ask how do I redirect Search Engines to take a second look on my new, fresh, rewritten URL-s?

So, my former URL-s were structured like this :

http://www.sample.com/tutorials.php?name=something

and now they look much more cleaner and better :

http://www.sample.com/tutorials/programming/something.php

So, as I said, I want Google (and other engines) to take a look at my new links, which are much more SEO friendly and for that I will be indexed better.

I was told the 301 redirect method was the best, but I don't have a clue what is it, how it works and where to learn how to use it. So, I am asking you.

Side note : Would updating my sitemap.xml file and re-submitting it to Google Webmaster Tools help in this process?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 kinds (in this context) redirects. When a client, be it a browser, search engine indexing bot, or whatever, requests a URI, the server can tell the client "What you are looking for exists, but it's somewhere else". In the case of a **302** or temporary redirect, it's essentially telling the client "What you are looking for exists, but it's temporarily over here at *this* URL". In the case of a **301** or permanent redirect, it's essentially telling the client "What you are looking for exists, but it has permanently moved over to *this* URL".

In the case of the later, browsers, proxy servers, and search engine indexes know that the old URL is no longer valid and to stop using it, and from now on to use the new URL that was returned by the server via a 301 redirect. In the case of a search engine like Google, it has an index of the old URL and all the data that its accumulated over the lifetime of that URL assoicated with it. When one of its bots sees a 301, it knows that the old URL, and its content, isn't gone, but it just permanently moved to another URL. All of the associated data Google has collected for the old URL gets trasnfered to the new URL. Google can probably figure most of this stuff out without a 301 redirect, but it's a sure way to make sure Google has got a right.

You can do such a redirect via mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /tutorials\.php\?name=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /tutorials/programming/%1.php [L,R=301]
```

You should put this near the top of the htaccess file in your document root. The condition checks that an actual request has been made for `/tutorials.php` with a query string `name="something"`. The "something" part gets grouped by the match and is accessed via the `%1` backreference.

Comment: Just to ask, would my "THE_REQUEST" be "HTTP_HOST", or something else? How do I decide what request should I use? I use a remote web-host (file transfer over FTP or cPanel).

Comment: @TheGhost `%{THE_REQUEST}` is a variable that stores the very first line of a browser's HTTP request, and it always looks something like this: `GET /some/URI/here HTTP/1.1`. You want to match against this because the URI changes as rewrite rules get applied, so if you blindly just match against the URI, things will loop. But if you match against the actual request that was sent by the browser, you know for sure you are redirecting correctly.

Comment: So, in my particular case, what would THE_REQUEST variable be?

Comment: @TheGhost It would look something like `GET /tutorials.php?name=something HTTP/1.1`

Comment: OK, thanks a lot! :) Just to ask, would name be equal to "(.+)", or to a real file name?

Comment: @TheGhost It is whatever your original request is for. I was using the URL in your question as an example: `http://www.sample.com/tutorials.php?name=something`, the `%{THE_REQUEST}` would be `GET /tutorials.php?name=something HTTP/1.1`. You can't use `(.+)` to match against the name's value because there's a space between the end of the URI and the `HTTP/1.1` protocol/version.

Comment: I see, so I if I have 50 tutorials for example, I would have to copy + paste it 50 times and change the URI?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16714/discussion-between-theghost-and-jon-lin)

Comment: @TheGhost No, the valie of the `name` parameter is captured by `([^&]+)` and used by the `%1` backreference. So if you type `http://www.sample.com/tutorials.php?name=blahblahblahblah` in your URL address bar, your browser will get redirected to `http://www.sample.com/tutorials/programming/blahblahblahblah`

Answer (score 0):

The 301 redirect is a response that the server can make which signals to the user (or search engine) that the page they are looking for has been permanently moved to a specified other page. It is possible to configure apache to give a 301 for certain urls, but it is probably easier to have the whatever server-side language you are using take the request, and then issue a 301.

The chances are that Google will work out what is going on fairly quickly without 301s or anything else, but submitting a sitemap to them or using the [URL Parameters](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1235687) functionality in Google's Webmaster Tools might help.